# Print selected documents in a document library SharePoint 2013 (bulk printing)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, printing

I have a SharePoint 2013 document library with folder and files. I have created a view on the library with certain filter conditions and to 'Show all items without folders'. I want to select couple of documents in the document library and be able to print the selected documents (bulk printing). 

Printing from Windows Explorer doesn't work for me because-

1. When i open in explorer view it shows folders and not selected documents.

2. I must dig deep into the folders and select the files again

Any references to third party tools or custom code helps**.